# Download a csv file from ftp with ruby sinatra

Tags: ruby, csv, ftp, sinatra

I have some ruby code that I'm using to download a csv file from an FTP server.

However, right now but it's not working and not showing any error message.

```
require 'net/ftp'
require 'net/ftp'
require 'fileutils'

get '/romil' do
 localfile = 'C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\test1.csv'
 ftp = Net::FTP.new(CONTENT_SERVER_DOMAIN_NAME)
 ftp.login CONTENT_SERVER_FTP_LOGIN, CONTENT_SERVER_FTP_PASSWORD
 ftp.passive = true

 files = ftp.chdir('abhi/')
 files = ftp.list
 puts "list out of directory:"
 puts files
 ftp.gettextfile('test.csv', localfile, 1024)

 ftp.close
end
```

Comment: Slight formating tweaks and spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks. I got the answer,
that's little bit tricky,
here is the working code :

```
get '/romil' do
   ftp = Net::FTP.open(CONTENT_SERVER_DOMAIN_NAME) do |ftp|
     ftp.login CONTENT_SERVER_FTP_LOGIN, CONTENT_SERVER_FTP_PASSWORD
     ftp.passive = true
     files = ftp.chdir('abhi/')
     files = ftp.list 
     puts "list out of directory:"
     puts files
     ftp.gettextfile('test7.csv') 
     filename = 'test7.csv'
     str = ''
   CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
     status 200
     headers \
     "Content-Type" => "text\\plain"
     str = str + row[0]  + ' ' + row[1]+ "\n"
   end
    body str
 end
end
```